# How to make Laravel use my class instead of native PDO?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, inheritance, pdo, laravel-5.1

I'm facing a big problem here. I work using laravel 5.1 and Sql Server 2012. The problem is:
All tables of my database have a trigger that is responsible to log activities on that table. This trigger do a insert after the insert on the main table. This way, every time I insert a new Person, the trigger will insert a new PersonLog.

This way, on Laravel when I do:

```
$person = Person::create(['personName' => 'Anderson']);
echo $person->id; //it tries to show me the log id instead of person id.
```

It happens because PDO uses `@@identity` variable to search for the last inserted id instead of use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Solutions:
 - I tried a pull request on laravel source using a manual query instead of pdo `lastInsertId()` method. It was denied.
 - The another solution **is create a class extending PDO and make laravel use my class instead of native pdo. But I don't have any idea of how to do it.**

Can you guys help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could alter the `config/app.php` to use your provider(s) (and facade) instead of the built in ones. Try looking into creating Laravel packages for a cleaner way to integrate stuff into your app, it's really not that hard and the reward is having an elegant approach that scales well.

Comment: I solved my issue using another solution. I've removed the primary key field from my log tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! 
It was really easy by the way, and I can't imagine how I didn't think on it. What did I do? Let me explain:

- First, I created a child from SqlServerGrammar inside my project
- In my SqlServerGrammar I override the compileInsert method
- In my AppServiceProvider on the boot method, I changed the grammar my connection use, this way: \DB::connection()->setQueryGramar(app(App\Classes\MyCustom\SqlServerGrammar::class));